# unexpected indent in ipython 0.10.1

Tags: python, indentation, ipython

I have a problem with ipython 0.10.1 in ubuntu 11.04 and python 2.7.1.

In previous versions of ipython indentation did not matter when working interactively.

Now instead any indented statement throws an exception:

```
In [1]:  a=3
------------------------------------------------------------
IndentationError: unexpected indent (<ipython console>, line 1)
```

this is really very annoying specifically when I am debugging and I want to paste some code from a script which is indented, and I am forced to undent every line.

Any hint welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens only when ipython is called with `-wthread`, I've just filed a [bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/573) about this.

Comment: do you think there my be a way of using -pylab without -wthread?

Comment: If I understand correctly, -pylab doesn't offer any benefits other from enabling support for a selected matplotlib backend, and you definitely cannot use runtime graphing without a -*thread argument.