# Workaround to allow leading whitespace in IPython

Tags: syntax, whitespace, indentation, ipython

My standard mode of working in Python is to edit a text file while having IPython open in a terminal. I write functions one line at a time and paste them one at a time into IPython. When a line is wrong i correct it in the text editor and then re-paste it.

This used to work well but recent versions of IPython won't accept indented code. One suggested solution is to use the qt terminal, but often I am logged in over an ssh session. Another suggested solution is to use %cpaste but that's two much overhead if you paste one line of indented code at a time (%cpaste at the beginning and -- at the end; 2 lines of overhead per line of code). What I currently do is unindent every block in my text editor before i start working on it, but that's a pain too. Any other ideas? What would be great is if there's a way to put IPython permanently into %cpaste mode, or whatever part of that mode makes it disregard leading whitespace.

See also:

[unexpected indent in ipython 0.10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682580/unexpected-indent-in-ipython-0-10-1)

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/573

thanks

Comment: "My standard mode of working..." Can you get a real IDE?  There are dozens.  There are a lot of better ways to work than this.  Have you considered that this is not optimal?

Comment: One advantage of the qtconsole is that it *does* work over ssh.  You can run the kernel on your server, and startup a qtconsole connected to it via ssh tunnels, and can continue to use the same kernel from various endpoints. [the relevant docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html#ssh-tunnels)

Comment: We have an open issue for precisely this, but it's low priority: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/995 . If you'd like to work on it, perhaps as an IPython extension, we'll happily give you pointers on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2436) that should fix this.  For large blocks delimited by multiple newlines, `%cpaste` is still recommended.